# Connecting to local docker containerised postgress DB - KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

Below is the error while local docker containerised postgres DB -

```
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): dist/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node dist/index.js`
seneca-base: Warning: trying to access process.env.NODE_V8_COVERAGE before environment has been initialized.
seneca-base: Warning: trying to access process.env.PG_FAST_CONNECTION before environment has been initialized.
seneca-base: Warning: trying to access process.env.NODE_PG_FORCE_NATIVE before environment has been initialized.
seneca-base: Warning: trying to access process.env.NODE_ENV before environment has been initialized.
{"name":"admin-server","hostname":"ShreeGaneshas-MacBook-Pro.local","pid":39289,"level":30,"port":9102,"scope":"seneca-base:metrics","msg":"Monitoring http server started on port 9102","time":"2023-09-01T08:34:56.980Z","v":0}
{"name":"admin-server","hostname":"ShreeGaneshas-MacBook-Pro.local","pid":39289,"level":30,"port":58080,"hooks":["senecaReady"],"scope":"seneca-base:http-health-check","msg":"HTTP Health check server started on port 58080","time":"2023-09-01T08:34:56.980Z","v":0}
lib-seneca: Warning: could not find client configuration and NO_CLIENTS env var is falsy.
{"name":"admin-server","hostname":"ShreeGaneshas-MacBook-Pro.local","pid":39289,"module":"lib-seneca","level":30,"seneca":{"pluginName":"-","level":300,"type":"-"},"msg":"[seneca.notice]: undefined","time":"2023-09-01T08:34:57.131Z","v":0}
{"name":"admin-server","hostname":"ShreeGaneshas-MacBook-Pro.local","pid":39289,"module":"lib-seneca","level":30,"seneca":{"pluginName":"-","level":300,"type":"INIT"},"payloadString":"{\n  \"kind\": \"listen\",\n  \"case\": \"INIT\",\n  \"data\": [],\n  \"callpoint\": \"at /Users/shreeganesha/Documents/Work/.../admin/services/admin-server/src/index.js:58:9\",\n  \"level\": 300,\n  \"isot\": \"2023-09-01T08:34:57.228Z\",\n  \"when\": 1693557297228,\n  \"level_name\": \"info\",\n  \"seneca_id\": \"nau5bogl24ao/1693557296985/39289/3.32.0/-\"\n}","msg":"[seneca.log.unknown]: check payloadString","time":"2023-09-01T08:34:57.228Z","v":0}
{"name":"admin-server","hostname":"ShreeGaneshas-MacBook-Pro.local","pid":39289,"level":30,"msg":"Service ready for use","time":"2023-09-01T08:34:57.229Z","v":0}
{"name":"admin-server","hostname":"ShreeGaneshas-MacBook-Pro.local","pid":39289,"level":30,"msg":"Server listening on port 3201","time":"2023-09-01T08:34:57.229Z","v":0}
KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
    at Client_PG.acquireConnection
```

Tried propagateCreateError: false & bumping up "pg" to latest version. Machine node version is 16.16.0.

Any clue will be really appreciated.